# TFS - Disable tracking changes on certain fields

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Under the 'All Changes' section under the 'History' tab of a Work Item, some have hundreds of changes.  How can I disable the field(s) I don't want to track changes of?

Answer (score 1):

You cant, all fields are tracked in TFS.

TFS & VSTS keep track of every value of every field in the system. All fields are tracked and there is no way to selectively track them.